# Magento: How do I display the mail address in the OPC progress bar?

Tags: email, magento

I am using Magento 1.9 and with older version, I was able to display the customers mail address in the onepage checkout progress bar using the following format:

```
{{depend email}}Mail: {{var email}}{{/depend}}
```

Suddenly, after updating to 1.9, this is not working anymore. Whats wrong with that? All other address parts still work the same.

Answer (score 0):

For Guest

```
{{var order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()}}
```

and for member

```
{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}
```

Comment: That wont work when defining the address format in the admin area, or will it? I cant differ between guest or logged in user.